# How to calculate current consumption of this sensor?

Tags: current

I am calculating the current consumption of an IR ranging detection sensor. Below is the related part I captured from the sensor's specification. The working mechanism of the sensor is that it will send out an IR beam, and then measure the elapse time when it receive back the beam.

From the table below, I think it means the sensor will take 33ms to take one measurement. So what does the "Active Ranging average consumption" actually means? How to calculate the current consumption if I take measurement every 0.5s, 1s and 2s?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The active ranging current is the current while measuring, the timing ranged inter measurement value is the current when not ranging. To get the total current multiply the two currents by the proportion of time you will be in each of the two states.

Assuming it takes 33ms for a range then your average power consumption in mA is:
0.033*n*19 + (1-0.033*n)*0.016
where n is the number of ranges per second.

So for 1Hz (n=1) the average current will be 0.64mA. For 10Hz (n=10) it would be 6.28mA.

With a nominal voltage of 2.8V this gives a power draw of 17.6mW Vs the 20mW number given in the table. However the 20mW is a maximum current consumption. The operating currents don't state a maximum but the standby currents do, they indicate that the maximum can be 40-50% over the typical values. Applying the same margin to the transmit currents would give 24mW power draw maximum. This is too high but it is reasonable that it's an over estimate, standby current is largely due to leakage currents which are more prone to process variability than operating currents. If we were to assume that the max operating current was only 10% over the typical then we get:
Max current = 0.033*n*19*1.1 + (1-0.033*n)*0.016*1.4
Which for 10 Hz ends up working out as 19.4mW.

So with a little bit of hand waving and reasonable assumptions it all seems to just about add up. A maximum current of just over 10% of typical seems like a reasonable tolerance to me.

Comment: I also calculated it exactly equal to your method. But I find that the resulting power does not match with the 20mW value when it is 10Hz. For 10Hz, if the average current is 6.28mA, the power should be 17.584mW, because the table say the voltage is 2.8V

Comment: Good point, I'd just assumed 3.3V. I'll modify my answer to reflect the voltage. However the 20mW is a max value, the current numbers are all typical values.

Comment: You are correct, the power is a max value.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet tells you that if you do a complete ranging cycle every 100 ms, the unit will draw 20 mW.  Since everything other than active ranging takes very little power, just assume that every ranging event takes 2 mJ.

Except for very long times where the standby current would actually be meaningful, just calculate the worst case as 2 mJ per event.  Or put another way, the power is inversely proportional to the ranging rate, with it being 20 mW at 10 Hz.  For example, at 2 Hz it takes 4 mW, at 1 Hz 2 mW.

Again, at very long intervals between ranging events, you need to take the standby power into account.  However, this won't be significant at just a few seconds ranging period.

Comment: I also tried this method, but I found that the result does not match with the method suggested by @Andrew (Using current to calculate instead of using power)